# Is there a word for a person with many creative ideas but little action?

Tags: vocabulary, pejorative-language

Is there a word in the English language that describes a personality type that has a creative mind and many ideas but for some reason (procrastinating, lack of energy or confidence, etc.) is not able to execute them? Maybe he or she is even satisfied with the things in his or her imagination and does not even try to make them real.

Is there a word for that?

Comment: "All light bulb and no electricity"?

Comment: A "utopist" or "pie in the sky inventor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "head-in-the-clouds"?  Another option would be "all plans".

Comment: It's not really what I was looking for, because, according to Wictionary, a head-in-the-clouds is someone with fantastic or impractical that are impossible or difficult to fulfill. While the person I'd like to describe has ideas that could well be executed, he/she just won't or can't do it. "All plans" sounds good, even though I've never heard or read it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

How about *[dark horse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dark-horse)* ?

> a ​person who ​keeps ​their ​interests and ​ideas ​secret, ​especially
>   someone who has a ​surprising ​ability or ​skill

Doesn't necessarily mean they keep their skills to themselves for lack of motivation, but I think it still is highly relevant to your definition.

Comment: The difference in UK and US meanings of this term is interesting—I had no idea of the UK sense of "dark horse." But Cambridge Dictionaries Online is a bit off-base in saying that the US sense of the term is “a horse or a politician who wins a race or competition although no one expected them to.” As definitions 1(a) and 1(b) in Merriam-Webster’s Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary indicate, winning is not a prerequisite: “**dark horse** 1831 1a: a usu. little known contender (as a racehorse) that makes an unexpectedly good showing 1b: an entrant in a contest that  is judged unlikely to succeed.”

Answer (score 1):

A **dreamer**.

SE want me to add filler text, but there is nothing more to say about this obvious word.

Comment: To add a technical connotation, an "ineffectual dreamer"..

Answer (score -1):

Type B personality,
Unmotivated,
Lethargic

Comment: [Friedman and Rosenman's type B personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_A_and_Type_B_personality_theory) has nothing to do with being unmotivated and lethargic.  I presume you mean another classification. Could you give references and links?

Answer (score -1):

Inaction bias

sample usage here: 
http://www.centralbanking.com/central-banking/news/2332463/esrb-handbook-calls-on-macro-prudential-regulators-to-overcome-inaction-bias

Comment: Your "sample usage" link goes to a page that invites readers to "Start a FREE trial or subscribe to continue reading." The example isn't visible to anyone who doesn't take one of those two steps. It would be much more helpful to readers if you reproduced the paragraph in which "inaction bias" is used in the article at CentralBanking.com, along with the link you already include for anyone who is willing to sign up at the site to see the whole article. In general, link-only (or link-mostly) answers at EL&U are much less useful to readers than answers that are visible in their entirety.